# Hover over bottom div to effect top div

Tags: css, css-selectors

Why is it that when I hover over the bottom div (`b`), it doesn't effect the top div (`a`): [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/u7tYE/3232/)

HTML:

```
<div id="a">Div A</div>
<div id="b">Div B</div>
```

CSS:

```
#b:hover #a {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/u7tYE/3233/

Comment: I think your link is wrong.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to press "update."

Comment: You're using a descendant combinator to select a previous sibling(there is no previous sibling selector) which wouldn't work. How about something like http://jsfiddle.net/u7tYE/3232/

Answer (score 1):

@drip is correct. It should be something like

```
#b:hover, #a:hover {
   background: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because **a** is not a child of **b**.

You are currently saying.
- When I **hover** on **B** change the color of my child **A**.

An since **a** is not child of **b**, your logic is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

With pure css it is not possible as *there is no "previous sibling" selector.*

You can select next sibling and use the effect like this

```
#a:hover + #b
{
    background-color:red;
}
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u7tYE/3235/)